# How to alter multiple objects in a data frame in R?

Tags: r, database, variables

I am working with a database that has 6 columns: 'cik', 'company.name', 'form.type', 'date.filed', 'nword.hits' and 'ticker'. The 'date.filed' column has objects of the following form: 2014-02-21, these numbers are dates. I would like to filter only the year and create a new column for this dataset, so that only the number 2014 remains. First I transformed the variables into as.character by the following code:

```
t <- transform(fdt, date.filed = as.character(date.filed))
```

Then, I separated the numbers by using following command:

```
bb <- strsplit(t$date.filed, split = "-")
```

In this way, the variables became as follows: '2014''02''21'.
In order to extract the years, I used the following code:

```
ex11 <- substr(bb, start = 1, stop = 8)
oficial <- data.frame(ex11)
```

I was able to extract the years, however they looked like this: c("2014". I wonder if there is any way to remove the c, the parentheses and the strings.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You could try `ex11 <- sapply(bb, "[", 1)`

Answer (score 3):

Instead of converting to `character` and then splitting or substring the dates, it may be better to convert to `Date` class and use the methods to extract those components

```
# // assuming the format to be in YYYY-MM-DD
fdt$date.filed <- as.Date(fdt$date.filed)
fdt$year <- as.integer(format(fdt$date.filed, "%Y"))
```

---

In the OP's code, output of `strsplit` is a `list` of `vector`s.  Instead of applying `substr` on the `list` (which is already splitted and just needs to extract the first component as in the comments), we need `substr` on the original column

```
substr(fdt$date.filed, 1, 4)
```

NOTE: For `Date` columns, the recommended solution is to use `Date` methods instead of regex or substring